# How we can create menu from Appearance > Menu and use as a add-submenu-page for admin menu?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, menus, wp-admin, admin

I'm working on the WordPress where I have multiple custom post type, but I want to know How we can create menu and use as a add-submenu-page for admin menu?

I want to create add menus from Appearance > Menu and create submenu to an admin menu

```
register_nav_menus(array(

'top-content' => 'Top Content',
'header-menu' => 'Header Menu',    
'adminsub-menu' => 'Admin Sub Menu',

 ));
```

Comment: You want to be able to add menus from _Appearance > Menus_ to an admin menu?

Comment: yes i want to create add menus from Appearance > Menu and create submenu to an admin menu is this possible if yes how can i do that?

Comment: please guide me how do i create function or use menu as a submenu in admin?

Comment: please provide me solution?

Comment: can any one provide me solution?

Comment: It is not currently possible to modify the dashboard/admin menu from the Nav Menu Editor without a relatively non-trivial amount of custom code. There may be a plugin which enables such functionality, but I'm not aware of it. All that in mind, it is unlikely that someone will furnish the necessary code from scratch given the amount of work involved in doing so. If you'd still like to pursue the issue, any code you can share from your attempt at an implementation will greatly increase the chances of receiving an answer.

Comment: @bosco okay i'm working on it i will share my code soon

Answer (score 0):

This plugin solved my issue (Seamlessly adds 3 new menu locations to the admin toolbar.)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-toolbar-menus/